# Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'

Tags: angular, ngx-share

I am using [`ngx-share`'s Share Button Directive](https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-sharebuttons/#/share-button-directive) in my project. However, I can't seem to be able to use the icons. If I try to use icons like this:

```xml
<button mat-fab shareButton="telegram" [style.backgroundColor]="share.prop.telegram.color">
  <fa-icon [icon]="share.prop.telegram.icon" size="lg"></fa-icon>
</button>
```

What I get is the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'.
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'icon' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("on mat-fab shareButton="telegram" [style.backgroundColor]="share.prop.telegram.color">
    <fa-icon [ERROR ->][icon]="share.prop.telegram.icon" size="lg"></fa-icon>
  </button>

"): ng:///AppModule/GroupComponent.html@49:13
'fa-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

  <button mat-fab shareButton="telegram" [style.backgroundColor]="share.prop.telegram.color">
    [ERROR ->]<fa-icon [icon]="share.prop.telegram.icon" size="lg"></fa-icon>
  </button>

"): ng:///AppModule/GroupComponent.html@49:4
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24674)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34629)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34604)
    at eval (compiler.js:34505)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34505)
    at eval (compiler.js:34375)
    at Object.then (compiler.js:475)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34374)
```

How can I fix this issue?

---

I added `ShareModule` to the list of imports:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //..
    ShareModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
```

My component also injects the `ShareButtons` object as required:

```js
export class GroupComponent {    
  constructor(public share: ShareButtons) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Which library is fa-icon part of? You need to import corresponding module

Comment: @David I don't know - I just follow the instructions on the website assuming that's all I have to do. Apparently the whole thing messes not with the compilation but introduces some other issues. After installing the packages auto-reloading (auto-compilation) does not work anymore. I have to remove the packages in order to make it work again ..

Comment: Can you share the link with the fa-icon example?

Comment: @David Of course: [Take a look](https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-sharebuttons/#/share-button-directive).

Comment: Now I get `Template parse errors: 'fa-icon' is not a known element`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Edit**
You can also import the 
`ShareButtonModule` which already exports the `FontAwesomeModule`.

**Original answer**

Assuming you've already installed the font awesome npm package, you need to add `FontAwesomeModule` to your module's imports

```js
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
 //...
imports: [
     //...
   FontAwesomeModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See example here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: Interesting - the moment I am installing this, auto-reloading breaks. If I make changes to the HTML, the projects does not get compiled anymore and the site is not getting refreshed...

Comment: Any error? In  console or in browser? Make sure you restart ng serve too if you installed anything

Comment: That's the best part and I think that's the reason why I might not have noticed the share buttons did already work earlier because I tried to install this module already. I am not getting an error or anything. I am killing `ng` and restart it `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` - it's just not doing anything anymore.

Comment: Since this solves the issues with ngx-share I'm going to accept this answer and open another one about the auto-reloading issue. [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076487/why-does-fortawesome-angular-fontawesome-break-auto-compilation) if you're interested. And thanks btw.

Comment: So ng serve compiles the code correctly though? Without error message there is not much I can do. But that original error you got definitely means that you are missing the fontawesome  module

Comment: Yes, it's getting compiled. No problem there. Only the auto-compile breaks :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `ShareButtonsModule` in the module where you are using these share buttons.

```js
import { ShareButtonsModule } from '@ngx-share/buttons';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ShareButtonsModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
```

Comment: That's what I did - according to the installation guide.

Comment: Btw I am trying to use the directive, not the component.

Comment: True, I had to add it to the correct module not to the app.module.ts and it helped

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had multiple modules in my angular app. I was importing it in app-module and using font awesome icon in other module, that was the issue, Importing it in the correct module file fixed the issue.