# Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon' (Ionic)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, font-awesome

This has really stumped me. I've done everything required, based on documentation and guidance here on SO. Font Awesome icons will not load in a submodule (component) - they load fine in top-level Ionic pages.

Here's what I have. First thing, npm installed font-awesome with:

```
npm i @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
npm i @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

Next, I've added the FontAwesomeModule to the app.module.ts file like so:

```
...
import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot({ mode: 'ios' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule, 
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
              provide: TranslateLoader,
              useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
              deps: [HttpClient]
          }
    }),
    FontAwesomeModule,
    PostComponentModule
  ],
  providers: [
    Calendar,
    ...
    Camera,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) { 
        library.addIconPacks(fas, fab, far);
    }
}
```

Created a PostComponentModule (post.module.ts, for the app-post component) to declare this submodule (component) - this was imported into the AppModule as well (see above)

```
import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { PostComponent } from './post.component';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    PostComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    PostComponent
  ]
})
export class PostComponentModule {
    constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) { 
        library.addIconPacks(fas, fab, far);
    } 
}
```

Then, for the page that uses this component, I've added the FontAwesomeModule as an import (feed.module.ts)

```
import { PostComponentModule } from '@grplife/components/post/post.module';
import { FaIconLibrary, FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    PostComponentModule,
    FeedPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [FeedPage]
})
export class FeedPageModule {
    constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) { 
        library.addIconPacks(fas, fab, far);
    } 
}
```

The post component is included in the feed template like (feed.page.html)

```
<app-post [postsData]="feed" [postRoute]="postRoute"></app-post>
```

The app-post component template has the following:

```
<button (click)="openPostView(post)">
    <fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'thumbs-up']"></fa-icon>
</button>
```

With all this, I'm getting the following and can't figure out the problem:

```
NG0303: Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon' (used in the 'PostComponent' component template).
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component and it has the 'icon' input, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Comment: Should be something related to importing correctly the modules: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50075931/5468463

Comment: `FeedPageModule` imports icons and makes them available to `FeedPage`, but not to its children. You should add import to the `app-post` component module (or the component itself in case it's standalone).

Comment: Thanks for the replies Vega and alx. Vega, I've read that post and updated my imports accordingly before posting this question. This didn't help. alx, as you can see above, the FontAwesomeModule is being imported into the app-post component module.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kyq2js?file=src/app/app.module.ts